# regexp for html tags with Matlab

Tags: regex, parsing, matlab, tags

I'm looking for a way to use regexp in order to remove all html tags from a string.

 So if I have `<HTML><b><FONT color="red" size="3">Hello</FONT></b></HTML>` I would like to get the `hello` from it.

I know it will probably look like nested tags, but it's not really, because all I want to do here is to remove anything between two `<>`.

I'm using Matlab for doing so, but the regexp is the exact same, so feel free to contribute any help. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution is:

```
>> str='<HTML><b><FONT color="red" size="3">Hello</FONT></b></HTML>';
>> regexprep(str, '<.*?>','')

ans =

Hello
```

Answer (score 5):

To match such a tag

```
<[^>]*>
```

See online [here at Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/NVi3BtyK8b)

Answer (score 3):

It is widely accepted that using regexes to parse general html is bad form.  If your html is much more complicated than the example given, then you should use an XML parser instead.

Further discussion in this famous SO question.  [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

If you want to parse the content properly, then download [xml_io_tools](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools) and use

```
doc = xml_read('test.html')
doc.b.FONT.CONTENT
```

If you want to stick with regexes, then use ilya's answer, but with one of the regexes from the linked answer, e.g.,

```
str = '<HTML><b><FONT color="red" size="3">Hello</FONT></b></HTML>';
rx = '<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>';
regexprep(str, rx, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you want to extract "hello" from the above html (say filename.html) file, you can use the following in MATLAB:

> > doc = xmlread('filename.html');
> >     content = doc.item(0).getTextContent

Hope this helps!