# ignore some strings with MATLAB

Tags: html, string, parsing, matlab

I would like to extract some text contained in HTML tags. For example:

```
<html><body>this is a warning message. wrongs values</body></html>
```

the result should get the message by ignoring all HTML tags.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: @Iola: This question is very poorly worded, so poorly that I can't even guess what you mean.  Please edit it, perhaps give some example inputs and outputs, show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: @Junuxx He means the markup symbols. HTML balise = french for HTML Markup (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_de_balisage)

Comment: btw: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582250/extracting-data-between-two-tags-in-html-file-matlab

Comment: Is that all you need to handle? Or do you need to handle other complex html constructions?

Comment: Yes, I would like to to get the message by ignoring html tags.

Comment: found an even closer duplicate: [regexp for html tags with Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867093/regexp-for-html-tags-with-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [strip HTML tags](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1W023G/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1W023G) using regular expressions:

```
str = '<html><body>this is a warning message. wrongs values</body></html>';
str2 = regexprep(str, '<[^>]*>', '')
```

Comment: Amro, could you please point me to some documentation on how creating regex with matlab , please ?

Comment: @lola: in the above expression, we look for the character `<` followed by zero or more occurrences `*` of anything except the right angle bracket `[^>]`, then the actual closing bracket `>`. The result is that we match `<....>` with anything in-between and simply replace it with empty string to remove it. There are many [resources](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html) online, you can play with [this](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%3C[^%3E]*%3E&input=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Ethis%20is%20a%20warning%20message.%20wrongs%20values%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A) tool

Comment: thanks Amro for your explanation, I've tried the tool but I don't know how use it ?

Comment: @lola: perhaps you should start by reading an [introductory tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
 a = sscanf('<html><body>this is a warning message. wrongs values</body></html>','<html><body>%[a-zA-Z., ]</body></html>')
```