# How to parse HTML tags in Matlab using regexp?

Tags: html, regex, matlab, tags

I'm short on time and specifically wanted to extract a string like the one below. Problem is the tag isn't of the form `<a> data </a>`.

Given,

```
s = <em style="font-size:medium"> 5,888 </em>
```

how to extract out just 5,888  in matlab?

Comment: @SagarMedikeri: There is no HTML parser in Matlab, for (I thought) obvious reasons. An alternative is to load the HTML into excel and use `xlsread` in Matlab. For general, arbitrary HTML, using `regex` to parse it is considered [a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), however, as stated in the second-most-upvoted answer there, if you have a known, small subset you want to parse, just go with `regex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks folks for your help. I'm basically trying to get the population of a US county on Matlab. Thought I'l share my code, though not the most elegant. Might help some soul. :)

```
county = 'morris';
state = 'ks';

county = strrep(county, ' ' , '+');
str = sprintf('https://www.google.com/search?&q=population+%s+%s',county,state);
s = urlread(str);
pop = regexp(s,'<em[^>]*>(.*?)</em>', 'tokens');
pop = char(pop{:});
pop = strrep(pop, ',' , '');
pop = str2num(pop);
```

Comment: You can also use `pop = regexp(s,'<em[^>]*>(.*?)</em>', 'tokens'); pop = cellfun(@(x) str2double(strrep(x,',','.')), [pop{:}])` to do everything in one go.

Answer (score 3):

You will find useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582250/extracting-data-between-two-tags-in-html-file-matlab), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867093/regexp-for-html-tags-with-matlab), or [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/110107), all of which are google-first-page results and would have been faster than asking a question here.

Anyway, quick-'n-dirty way: You can filter on the `<>` symbols:

```
>> s = '<em style="font-size:medium"> 5,888 </em> <sometag> test </sometag>'    
>> a = regexp(s, '[<>]');    
>> s( cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y)x:y, a(2:2:end-1)+1, a(3:2:end)-1, 'uni',false)) )

ans = 

   5,888 test
```

Or, slightly more robust and much cleaner, replace everything between any tags (including the tags) with emptyness:

```
>> s = regexprep(s, '<.*?>', '')
ans = 

   5,888 test
```

Comment: Thanks Rody, your third link helped me! I used 
pop = regexp(s,'<em[^>]*>(.*?)</em>', 'tokens')