# Save the website text and eliminate the <tag> in source code

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I get the text only in the webpage when given html file and eliminate all the tag, <> ,
here I only can get the tag, <> in the from the html file, how to work it the other way round (get the text).

```
tag_only = regexp(CharData, '<.*?>', 'match');
```

For example:

```
"<p><span class="dingus">&#9658;</span> put returns between paragraphs</p>StackExchange.ready(function () {
        StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
            StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
        });
```

"

Output: put returns between paragraphs

Comment: why are you using Matlab to parse html pages? This is really really the wrong language for that. Anyway, your question makes little sense. What do you mean get the text of a webpage? Some of the text may be generated dynamically by javascript. Or some of the text on the html may be hidden by javascript so it would actually not be displayed.

Comment: i have to use matlab because html parser is just 1 of my features. so, d u mean other languages are more benefits in doing this, is that python?

Comment: if is python, then do u have any idea to do this, im urgently need for that.

Comment: python or perl are just the two most common and both have many many html parsers. Googling for html parser perl or python will certainly return many hits. And just because the rest of your program will need to use Matlab, it doesn't mean that you can't write this part in another language. Programs can communicate between each other.

Comment: yes, i do not use python before, so, do you have this program so that i do not need to write by myself. I have look through these prob using python, there are a lots, do you have any recommendation or straight can use program to intro, because im running out of time

Comment: See the example in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) for how to get the "data" from html. Don't even try to do this properly in Matlab because you only know Matlab. The time it will take to write that, will be much large than the time it will take to do learn another language.

Comment: If you can find the things you don't want, it should not be too hard to remove them.

Comment: but i got lots of criteria to check, i dun want eg:<tag>, function ...etc, plus i dun have idea to eliminate this, i only know how to keep this...any ideas?

Comment: Replace all tags by an empty string, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227160/how-to-parse-html-tags-in-matlab-using-regexp

Answer (score 0):

I dont know matlab but you can try to change the regexp:

```
tag_only = regexp(CharData, '>.*?<', 'match');
```

or

```
tag_only = regexp(CharData, '>[^<]*?<', 'match');
```

or

```
tag_only = regexp(CharData, '>[^<]+<', 'match');
```

I agree that with python would be easier, check the library ElementTree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print(child.text)
```

I havent try this code but it shouldnt be far from it.

Comment: i try edi, but it does not work for function which dun have the <>, with these "><", some may return the wrong results. eg:button><

Comment: it return me the "'div><'    'div><'    'div><'    'body><'    'html>'" as well.

Comment: what about I get all the <> first then save in text file, then get the full html file and minus with the <> file, then i will the the webtext. is it possible? I do not know how to take "full html file" - "<>tag file" = "web text". any ideas?

Comment: did u try other options?

Comment: do u mean other html parser like python? im still looking for it

Comment: how 2 use it? izit the same concept as this 1? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html
i have to open new matlab editor and put in the above code izit?

Comment: Try to replace all tags by an empty string, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227160/how-to-parse-html-tags-in-matlab-using-regexp

Comment: yes, it works for me with all the tag, answer is almost there but now still left over the function code, i want to eliminate all the thing and left only the website content, any ideas?

Comment: It's super dirty but you can do de same, replace "StackExchange.ready(.*});"  by an empty string.

Comment: i use the "s = regexprep(s, '<.*?>', '')", so if "replace "StackExchange.ready(.*});" by an empty string" is....?

Comment: 2 commands: first "s = regexprep(s, '<.*?>', '')" and finally "final = regexprep(s, 'StackExchange.ready(.*});', '')"

Answer (score 0):

You can call Java directly from Matlab ([see](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html)).

There you have a wide choice of Html parsers. Just pick one. [This](http://jsoup.org/) looks ok - but you have the [choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers).

Comment: why i fail to open all of it after downloading 3 of them? it show me fail to load......i downloaded d installer at here http://jsoup.org/download

Comment: i got try with this before, i could not open the installer after I downloaded, i can only use the online html parser http://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: You need to clearly state what you did and what the error was. There is no installer to download - just the library. I think you need to carefully follow my first link to "call Java directly from Matlab".