# How to read and split words of a text file and then save in a single variable (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, strsplit

Given below is my text inside a text file:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>annotations/01/1515.eng</DOCNO>
<TITLE>Yacare Ibera</TITLE>
<DESCRIPTION>an alligator in the water;</DESCRIPTION>
<NOTES></NOTES>
<LOCATION>Corrientes, Argentina</LOCATION>
<DATE>August 2002</DATE>
<IMAGE>images/01/1515.jpg</IMAGE>
<THUMBNAIL>thumbnails/01/1515.jpg</THUMBNAIL>
</DOC>
```

How to split the words inside it a store in a single variable, like

`x = 'annotations' '1515.eng' 'Yacare'` ...and so on?

Comment: Have you even tried something before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also regexp might help you. Please check it in matlab's help.

Comment: Something like [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867093/regexp-for-html-tags-with-matlab) may help you get started at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two steps. First is to extract string between tags. Second is to split the extracted string using delimiters. I assume that the delimiters are `/` and (space). I also assume that your string is loaded from some file using `importdata` function.

Then

```
% load string from a file
STR = importdata('testin');

% extract string between tags
B = regexprep(STR, '<.*?>','');

% split each string by delimiters and add to C
C = [];
for i=1:length(B)
    if ~isempty(B{i})
        C = [C strsplit(B{i}, {'/', ' '})];
    end
end
```

Comment: Sir, i am trying to use importdata for multiple files but is not accessing all files but reads just one file, how can i use multiple text files for this

Comment: you just need to call `importdata` for each file.

Comment: i have 122 text files, how i am suppose to call import data for each file. i gave path for each file using for loop, but it doesn't work.

Comment: means it only reads one file. I wrote this command--sdirectory = `'C:\Users\anurag\Desktop\Animals\Annotations\';`
`textfiles = dir([sdirectory '/*.eng']);`
`for k = 1:length(textfiles)`
`file = [sdirectory '/' textfiles(k).name];`
`STR = importdata(file);`
`B = regexprep(STR, '<.*?>','');`
`C = [];`
`for i=1:length(B)`
   ` if ~isempty(B{i})`
      `  C = [C strsplit(B{i}, {'/', ' '})];`
   ` end`
`end`
`end`

Comment: Sir, i have provided the code. Now how to use importdata over all files

Comment: i want to split strings in each text file so that i could check the occurrence of my query words in the string. Example- given all text files, find which text file contains words from query string.

Comment: Please post it as another question.